# Explanation of Func

Tags: c#, .net, func

I was wondering if someone could explain what `Func<int, string>` is and how it is used with some clear examples.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Are you familiar with delegates in general? I have a page about [delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) which may help if not, although it's more geared towards explaining the differences between the two.

[`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) is just a generic delegate - work out what it means in any particular situation by replacing the *type parameters* (`T` and `TResult`) with the corresponding *type arguments* (`int` and `string`) in the declaration. I've also renamed it to avoid confusion:

```
string ExpandedFunc(int x)
```

In other words, `Func<int, string>` is a delegate which represents a function taking an `int` argument and returning a `string`.

`Func<T, TResult>` is often used in LINQ, both for projections and predicates (in the latter case, `TResult` is always `bool`). For example, you could use a `Func<int, string>` to project a sequence of integers into a sequence of strings. *Lambda expressions* are usually used in LINQ to create the relevant delegates:

```
Func<int, string> projection = x => "Value=" + x;
int[] values = { 3, 7, 10 };
var strings = values.Select(projection);

foreach (string s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Result:

```
Value=3
Value=7
Value=10
```

Comment: "In other words, it's a delegate which represents a function taking an int argument and returning a string."

Just to avoid confusion for others I will clearify that you are talking about Func<int, string> here and not Func<T, TResult>.
It is obvious if you understand generic types and delegates but for those who dont it is Func<int, string> that kan delegate to a function that takes a int argument and returns a string.

Comment: Will clarify when I'm back on a PC later.

Comment: I think this actually is not as clear as MSDN's description and example.  I also think you should add information about how the last type param is the return type - clarifying that Func<int, int, string> returns string and takes 2 ints.  That helps clarify.  Nothing personal - I just didn't think it was clear enough.

Comment: So are you going to downvote every answer which you deem to be not as helpful as your particular favourite? Is this answer actively *unhelpful*, do you think? Do you think that perhaps having more than one way of looking at things might not be a bad idea?

Comment: Thanks jon this helped clarify certain things that were confusing to me.

Comment: Cool. Out of interest, could you share the exact points of confusion? That could help make further explanations even clearer - because anything that you find confusing is likely to be confusing others too.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi: No, of course, no reason to take your downvote personally - the fact that you *did* downvote for personal reasons on Saturday and then just *happened* to come into this thread after we've been having a long discussion on email about appropriate behaviour is *entirely* coincidental, isn't it?

Answer (score 41):

A `Func<int, string>` eats ints and returns strings.  So, what eats ints and returns strings?  How about this ...

```
public string IntAsString( int i )
{
  return i.ToString();
}
```

There, I just made up a function that eats ints and returns strings.  How would I use it?

```
var lst = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string str = String.Empty;

foreach( int i in lst )
{
  str += IntAsString(i);
}

// str will be "12345"
```

Not very sexy, I know, but that's the simple idea that a lot of tricks are based upon.  Now, let's use a Func instead.

```
Func<int, string> fnc = IntAsString;

foreach (int i in lst)
{
  str += fnc(i);
}

// str will be "1234512345" assuming we have same str as before
```

Instead of calling IntAsString on each member, I created a reference to it called fnc (these references to methods are called [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80).aspx)) and used that instead.  (Remember fnc eats ints and returns strings).

This example is not very sexy, but a ton of the clever stuff you will see is based on the simple idea of functions, delegates and [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

One of the best primers on this stuff I've seen is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/FP-Tutorial.aspx).  He's got a lot more real examples. :)

Comment: @Therealnapster i like it too but I like your name more.

Answer (score 29):

It is a delegate that takes one `int` as a parameter and returns a value of type `string`.

Here is an example of its usage:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<Int32, String> func = bar;

        // now I have a delegate which 
        // I can invoke or pass to other
        // methods.
        func(1);
    }

    static String bar(Int32 value)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks andrew. Did you mean to write func(1) instead of bar(1)?

Answer (score 1):

`Func<int, string>` accepts an int value parameter and returns a string value. Here's an example where an additional supporting method is unnecessary.

```
Func<int, string> GetDogMessage = dogAge =>
        {
            if (dogAge < 3) return "You have a puppy!";
            if (dogAge < 7) return "Strong adult dog!";

            return "Age is catching up with the dog!";
        };

string youngDogMessage = GetDogMessage(2);
```

NOTE: The last object type in Func (i.e. "string" in this example) is the functions return type (i.e. not limited to primitives, but any object).  Therefore, `Func<int, bool, float>` accepts int and bool value parameters, and returns a float value.

```
Func<int, bool, float> WorthlessFunc = (intValue, boolValue) =>
        {
            if(intValue > 100 && boolValue) return 100;

            return 1;
        };
float willReturn1 = WorthlessFunc(21, false);
float willReturn100 = WorthlessFunc(1000, true);
```

HTH