# How to use UnitOfWOrk .GetByCondition()

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, repository

i have a generic repository

```
    public TEntity GetByCondition(Func<TEntity, Boolean> where)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<TEntity>();
    }
```

i need to get the selected records based on condition;

```
    public IEnumerable<ResultEntity> GetResultByParams(string _RollNo, string _Class)
    {
      var result = _unitOfWork.ResultRepository.GetByCondition(); // i need to check ondition of _RollNo here. Please guide me the usage. 
    }
```

// how to use the var result = _unitOfWork.ResultRepository.GetByCondition(); with condition

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
var result = _unitOfWork.ResultRepository.GetByCondition(res => /*your condition for "result" here*/);
```

By condition I mean expression that returns bool.

For example:

```
var result = _unitOfWork.ResultRepository.GetByCondition(res => res.RollNo == _RollNo);
```

It basically means: "give me all Results which have `RollNo` equals to `_RollNo`"

I recommend you to read explanations of Func from following question, it may be useful: [Explanation of Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878650/explanation-of-func).

And, of course, [msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) for the type of Func-s used in your case.

Comment: I need to have record in return. not true false

Comment: Error 3 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DataModel.tbl_Result'.  'Where' not found. E:\Dump\taskapi\api\BusinessServices\ResultService\ResultService.cs 41 45 BusinessServices

Comment: My answer is not implying that you'll receive a bool instead of entity. I just show how to use your method `GetByCondition` using lambda expression.

Comment: This error is not seems to be related to any of I wrote in answer. If you'll provide more context (for example, line of code where error occurs), i'll try to help.

Comment: Error 3 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DataModel.tbl_Result'. 'Where' not found

Comment: Please guide me, I am using RepositoryPattern first time

Comment: if (result != null)
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<tbl_Result, ResultEntity>();
                var resultInfo = from rs in result // here getting error
                                 where rs.RollNo == _RollNo && rs.Class == _Class
                                 orderby rs.ID descending
                                 select rs;
                var ResultModel = Mapper.Map<List<tbl_Result>, List<ResultEntity>>(resultInfo.ToList());
                return ResultModel;
            }
            return null;

Comment: OK, let's clarify: you have GetByCondition method of your repository and you have no idea what to pass as argument, right? Well, if so, I just showed in answer what you should pass there: it's lambda expression, which body should return bool (specifying a condition for your entities).

Comment: As for error, it's probably conflict of names. Try to rename `result` from my example to anything else, for example to `entity` and see if error persists.

Comment: I changed but the same

Comment: can I use direct query to entity like;

Comment: var context = new taskAPIDBEntities();
            var query = context.tbl_Result.Where(x => x.RollNo == _RollNo).Single();

Comment: If it is not the conflict, and `result` is meant to be the result of GetByCondition then the problem is that you trying to apply LINQ to SQL language syntax (`from rs in result...`) to something that has not `Where` method. In this case it is ResultEntity which obviously has not such method (it would make sense if GetByCondition returned IQueryable of IEnumerable, but it returning a single entity).

Comment: Yes, you can, but doing this you're definetely not using repository pattern.

Comment: And, by the way, if this is the DbContext, you should use `using` or at least dispose your `context` later, when you're done.

Comment: like this: using(var context = new taskAPIDBEntities()) {  /*do you staff here, it'll automatically dispose since you'll leave this code block*/  }

Comment: yes, again giving the error: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1<DataModel.tbl_Result>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1<DataModel.tbl_Result>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq` in the file? `DbSet` is `DbQuery` which implements IQueryable, so `Where` here should be an extension method `System.Linq.Queryable.Where`.

Comment: '<select class="form-control" name="companyId" id="selectedClass">
                                                            @foreach (ACD_Class _class in ViewBag.Class)
                                                            {
                                                                <option value="@_class.ClassID" @(Request["classId"] == @_class.ClassID.ToString() ? "selected=''" : "")>@_class.ClassTitle</option>
                                                            }
                                                        </select>'

Comment: trying to pass value from selected item to Request