# How to call method with Func<string, T> as one of parameter

Tags: c#

I have a class `RemoteData` like below,

```
public class RemoteData
{
    public RemoteData(string Message, string IP)
    {
        this.IP = IP;
        this.Message = Message;
    }

    public string IP;
    public string Message;
}
```

Now I have a `IObservable<T>` method `UdpStream` like below,

```
 public static IObservable<RemoteData> UdpStream(IPEndPoint endpoint, Func<string, RemoteData> processor)
    {
        return Observable.Using(() => new UdpClient(endpoint),
            udpClient => Observable.Defer(() => 
                udpClient.ReceiveAsync().ToObservable()).Repeat().Select(result => processor(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Buffer))));
    }
```

Now how to call `UdpStream`, how to pass `Func` parameter?

```
var stream = UdpStream(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514), 2nd Param);
```

Comment: read thru all of the answers here and you will understand - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878650/explanation-of-func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Func<T, U>` represents a delegate that takes a `T` parameter and returns `U`. You can initialize a `Func<T, U>` using a method reference that matches that signature, or using a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

Using a `Func<,>` as parameter is a common idiom for a callback. For example, if you have a method similar to this:

```
public static void Method(Func<T, U> func)
{
     // ...
}
```

We can expect that `Method` will call whaterver you pass in the `func` parameter. In fact, this happens in the code your present (the parameter `Func<string, RemoteData> processor` is called where it says `processor(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Buffer))`).

---

Now, you have `Func<string, RemoteData>`, thus you need a method that takes `string` and returns `RemoteData`. For example:

```
public static RemoteData Example(string input)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

var observable = UdpStream(endpoint, Example);
```