# Understanding C# method of Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string>

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have this code from a different source where the objective is reading a CSV file after it matches a defined schema and then copying it into a tabular database. before copying the file into the tabular database, it is necessary for the CSV file to have these two columns: `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`. If the partition key is not there then it should take the ID which is being passed as an argument. Below is the code and I don't understand what `Func<Dictionary<>,string>` part is doing. Can someone please explain to me what it is being used for and how it works?

// the main function WriteToTable is called like this:

```
 await WriteToTable(lines, dataclass,
                p => documentId,
                p => $"{dataclass.SubType}_{p["RowKey"].Int32Value.Value.ToString("D10")}", upsert);
```

//Write To Table

```
public async Task WriteToTable(string lines, DataClass dataclass,
            Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genPartitionKey,
            Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genRowKey, bool upsert)
        {
            const int BatchSize = 100;
            if (HasPartitionAndRowKey(dataclass.TableSchema.Fields))
            {
                genPartitionKey = (Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props) => props["PartitionKey"].StringValue;
                genRowKey = (Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props) => props["RowKey"].ToString();
            }

            var tableRecords =ReadCSV(lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields)
                .Select(props => new DynamicTableEntity(genPartitionKey(props), genRowKey(props), string.Empty, props))
                .ToList();
            await batchInsertIntoTableStorage(BatchSize,tableRecords, upsert);
           

        }

static readonly string[] RequiredTableKeys = { "PartitionKey", "RowKey" };

        private bool HasPartitionAndRowKey(List<TableField> fields)
        {
            return fields.Select(f => f.Name).Intersect(RequiredTableKeys).Count() == RequiredTableKeys.Length;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation of Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878650/explanation-of-func)

Comment: Func Is used as Anonymous delegate  in c# which have one return type and and other as parameters of func.  Delegate  is function pointer that you can use inside function as parameter          in your case  used two  funcs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the simplest way how func work

```
public bool Validate(Func<string,bool> dependentMethod)
{
    string parmeter = "after execution inside method";
    bool isvalid = dependentMethod(parmeter);

    return isvalid;

}

public bool DependentMethod(string input)
{
    // process  there statement and return out put after your business logics

    return true;
}

public void CheckValidation()
{
    bool isValid= Validate(DependentMethod);
}
```

According to Your Method

```
public async Task WriteToTable(string lines, DataClass dataclass,
        Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genPartitionKey,
        Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genRowKey, bool upsert)
```

this is your method header  and here have two  func genPartitionKey,genRowKey

in implementation

```
 if (HasPartitionAndRowKey(dataclass.TableSchema.Fields))
        {
            genPartitionKey = (Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props) => props["PartitionKey"].StringValue;
            genRowKey = (Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props) => props["RowKey"].ToString();
        }
```

if check is true then he reassign your method
  `genPartitionKey=(Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props)=>{return props["RowKey"].ToString();}`

and same that for the second one

and in this expression he called these both methods
 `var tableRecords =ReadCSV(lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields).Select(props => new DynamicTableEntity(genPartitionKey(props), genRowKey(props), string.Empty, props)).ToList();`

as I called it

`Validate(DependentMethod);`

Comment: can you please explain relating to my code?

Comment: i hope now you can understand it